# Re-evaluate div height on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a shopping cart that has all the main functions on the left hand side and i have a right hand side column that displays recommended products to the buyer etc... I have set this div to match the height of the main div using this js:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
       var target = $('.height-wrapper').height();
       $('.rightcolumn').height(target -2);
       var target2 = $('.height-wrapper2').height();
       $('.rightcolumn2').height(target2 -2);
});
```

This all works fine, however now i would like to have the right hand column height re-evaluate on any click event, so if an item is added from this recommended products column into the shopping cart the height of the right column will alter again, or when i expand a collapsed div i have in the main div.

How to I write the Jquery to work not just on window load but also to re-evaluate the height upon a click function...?

Answer (score 1):

You can place your code snippet in a function, then call that function when you need it:

```
function evaluateHeight(){
    var target = $('.height-wrapper').height();
    $('.rightcolumn').height(target -2);
    var target2 = $('.height-wrapper2').height();
    $('.rightcolumn2').height(target2 -2);
}

$(window).on('load', evaluateHeight);
$element.click(evaluateHeight);
```

Comment: @charlotteg `$element` is junt an exemple, this should be the div you want to evaluate.

Comment: `$element.click()` is a placeholder I've just made up. That is the event handler called by whatever it is you need clicked when the height should be re-evaluated.

Comment: Hahaha silly me, replaced it with $('.rightcolumn') but it still doesn't work! But wait, isn't element referring to any element that is clicked? i want to cover any click event not just clicking inside the .rightcolumn if that makes sense @RicardoAlvaroLohmann

Comment: Ok i can figure out to target the buttons for the recommended products that would add it to the shopping cart but how do i target a radio button, i have a div that slides down if the radio button is checked, only radio button on page so id not so neccessary. @George

Comment: Simply [select the buttons](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) that you want to cause the column to update and then attach your event handler.